# Is there a way to make mock functions "interesting" with ON_CALL?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

Given:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include <string>

using namespace testing; // tsk, tsk

// -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

struct Mockable {
    virtual std::string ify(int x) const;
};

std::string Mockable::ify(int x) const
{
    return std::to_string(x);
}

// -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

struct Mocked : public Mockable {
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(ify, std::string(int));
};

// -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

std::string tested(Mockable const& u, int x)
{
    return u.ify(x);
}

TEST(TC,T42)
{
    Mocked mock;
    ON_CALL(mock, ify(Eq(42)))
    .WillByDefault(Return("33"));

    std::string const& ret = tested(mock, 42);
    EXPECT_EQ("42", ret);
}

TEST(TC,T33)
{
    Mocked mock;
    ON_CALL(mock, ify(Eq(33)))
    .WillByDefault(Return("333"));

    std::string const& ret = tested(mock, 42);
    EXPECT_EQ("42", ret);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    //::testing::FLAGS_gmock_verbose = "info";

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./mocktest 
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from TC
[ RUN      ] TC.T42

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
mocktest.cc:40:
    Function call: ify(42)
          Returns: "33"
Stack trace:
mocktest.cc:44: Failure
Value of: ret
  Actual: "33"
Expected: "42"
[  FAILED  ] TC.T42 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] TC.T33

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: ify(42)
          Returns: ""
Stack trace:
mocktest.cc:54: Failure
Value of: ret
  Actual: ""
Expected: "42"
[  FAILED  ] TC.T33 (1 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from TC (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 2 tests, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] TC.T42
[  FAILED  ] TC.T33
```

In both cases, Gmock behaves correctly w.r.t. applying the behavior (or not, in TC33). But why does it say "Uninteresting mock function call" in both cases? Are mock function calls interesting only when specified with `EXPECT_CALL` ?

Comment: Use `::testing::nice_mock<Mocked>  mock;` to avoid these warning for not explictely expected calls on a mock.

Comment: Maybe [this will help](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#I_got_a_warning_"Uninteresting_function_call_encountered_-)

Comment: Doh! I only checked the gmock cookbook and cheatsheet :(

Comment: @Bulletmagnet Here's some more info about [`NiceMock<>`](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#The_Nice,_the_Strict,_and_the_Naggy), sorry for the typos.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> *"Are mock function calls interesting only when specified with EXPECT_CALL ?"*

In short, yes.
The `ON_CALL()` macro only influences the action to be taken on a mock method call, but not the call expectations set on the mock object.

You can use the `NiceMock<>` template though, to suppress these warnings in general.
[To cite from google mocks "Cookbook"](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#the-nice-the-strict-and-the-naggy)

> Suppose your test uses a mock class MockFoo:

```
TEST(...) {
  MockFoo mock_foo;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_foo, DoThis());
  ... code that uses mock_foo ...
}
```

> If a method of mock_foo other than DoThis() is called, it will be reported by Google  Mock as a warning. However, if you rewrite your test to use NiceMock instead, the warning will be gone, resulting in a cleaner test output:

```
using ::testing::NiceMock;

TEST(...) {
  NiceMock<MockFoo> mock_foo;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_foo, DoThis());
  ... code that uses mock_foo ...
}
```

> `NiceMock<MockFoo>` is a subclass of `MockFoo`, so it can be used wherever `MockFoo` is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use **EXPECT_CALL** with **WillRepeatedly**:

`EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoThis()).WillRepeatedly(Return("42"));`